# Free Crash Reporting for Xamarin Forms ( UWP, Android, iOS)

Tags: windows, gratis, android, cross-platform, reporting

Anyone has any to recommend? I have heard of Hockey, Insights, and Firebase but these aren't free.
I'm looking for free open source solution, something like [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) for Android, preferably to report errors in an email but open for other means of reporting.
I'm interesting in collecting primarily crash reporting providing call stack information but other useful reporting is more than welcome.

Comment: I'm not a dev and thus don't know an answer anyway – but [according to our rules](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) you should be a trifle more specific. Also take a look at [How to ask for an alternative to some software](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185). Missing: what features do you need (eg. what details must be covered, what should the Dashboard contain, etc.)? It will certainly not be sufficient to just have a counter increased whenever a crash happens – or does it? :)

Comment: So, you cant something to catch exceptions & inform you? If so, how? By email or what? As @izzy said, please read [ask] and remember that the more information that you give us, the more that we can help you.  I added the [tag:gratis] since you want a free solution; if you have a budget in mind, state your budget in the question and remove the tag

Comment: If it didn't say how to report, then it does not matter to me how but email would be most logical so preferred way.  Free means free, no budget in mind, looking for free open source

Comment: Thanks, @dbnex14 – might need a few more details (devs could say which, but I could e.g. think of on what events it should fire and what details it should collect), but I'd say it's clear enough to be reopened now (done that). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could try [RollBar](https://rollbar.com/). They have a free plan that allows for 5,000 events a month and retain data for 30 days. I use them at work and I actually really like them.

- They work with multiple languages including IOS, Android, .Net, PHP,
  ROR, JavaScript.
- You can set which environment (dev, stage or production) the events are coming from.
- You to keep track of code deployments, which then will allow you diagnose when the error started showing up.
- They will email you a daily summary, and when an error starts occurring to many times within a few minutes.

  I also found a [GitHub project for hooking Rollbar up with Xamarin](https://github.com/lanarchyste/Xamarin.RollbarDotNet).

Comment: Would you mind elaborating bit, what do you like or dislike about it?  What do you use it for and in which platform?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Currently, I dislike how they don't have a way to add deployments through their web interface ( you have to hit their API) and how sometimes the line number where an error happens isn't always accurate. You can group errors together, which could be the reason the line number isn't always accurate. Beyond that, I really like it.